# During Downloading File using WebClient i got an error access is denied?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, window

> While Downloading file to particular path I got error access is denied where i want to save my file,I already give permissions to that folder

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
   string pathfromdownloadfile="C://....";
   string DownloadPath="D://..."
   client.DownloadFile(pathfromdownloadfile, DownloadPath);    
  }
```

is There any solution,

Comment: If you are getting something from C drive, you may need more access, If this happen on server, check the permission of aspnetuser.

Comment: Sir How Can i check permission of aspnetuser

Comment: #Anirudha ,If I will give any folder ,Suppose i want to to download file from (D: drive) and  also download it in (D: drive) then Same i got this error

Comment: can you tell us the exact exception that you are getting?

Comment: @Nav then you don't need to use WebClient, Simply try with copy or move from System.IO. WebClient is used for download thing from internet, In your case you are downloading thing that is exist in your own PC.

Comment: @Anirudha ,Actually I am creating window application, And When I trying to run debug then it shows that ("An exception occurred during a WebClient request") in Catch method ,and when i expand this then i found ("Access to Path is denied")

Comment: @Anirudha , Your Second Suggestion(Simple copy and move) is good and it works thanks